# .Net Website Deployment - Deploy to port other than Default Web Site

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment

I have a server that I need to deploy a website too (website already exists on the server, but I have an update to publish), but the website doesn't live under the "Default Web Site" on the server. Instead it lives under a named "Sharepoint - 80" site. Looks like I can't think publish the site via `\\servername\wwwroot$` as it doesn't live there. How do I go about publishing to this other site?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the properties of "Sharepoint - 80" in IIS manager to determine where the physical files are located, then you can publish your update there.

Comment: Hmm...even this doesn't seem right...I checked the Home Directory of this named site and its the exact same as if it was the Default Web Site "Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80". Shouldn't I be able to publish this with the standard wwwroot$\AppName publish? When I try that I'm getting a "Web site doesn't exist/unable to create it" error?

Comment: I just meant that you can check the settings in IIS to locate the local path, and then you can determine what the share path should be from there.